# [__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument' error

Tags: ios, printing, nsmutablestring

I was trying to show string values in print preview option.If i didn't enter any text in any of the textfield and while clicking print button the app gets crashed.And the error is [__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'.Here is my code

```
-(NSMutableString*)pageStringToPrint {

    NSMutableString * cnoteString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [cnoteString setString:@"Class: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.cnote.classname];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nTeacher: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.cnote.teacher];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nSource: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.cnote.source];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nTopic: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.cnote.topic];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.cnote.date];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nDate: "];
    [cnoteString appendString: dateString];  

    cnoteString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div id=\"mainContainer\"><div id=\"header\">%@</div>",[cnoteString kv_encodeHTMLCharacterEntities]];
```

This is how i created Self.cnoe.classname

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self saveCNote ];
    self.classNameTextField.text = self.cnote.classname;
    self.topicTextField.text = self.cnote.topic;
    self.sourceTextField.text = self.cnote.source;
    self.teacherTextField.text = self.cnote.teacher;


    self.essentialQuestionTextView.placeholder = @"Essential Question";
    self.essentialQuestionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
    self.essentialQuestionTextView .layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    self.essentialQuestionTextView.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
    self.essentialQuestionTextView.delegate = self;
    self.essentialQuestionTextView.text = self.cnote.essentialQuestion;

    // set the date
    self.dateTextField.delegate = self;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    self.dateTextField.text = [dateFormat    stringFromDate:self.cnote.date];
  }
```

Save Cnote:

```
- (void)saveCNote {

    self.cnote.classname = self.classNameTextField.text;
    self.cnote.topic = self.topicTextField.text;
    self.cnote.source = self.sourceTextField.text;
    self.cnote.teacher = self.teacherTextField.text;


    [self.cnote save];
}
```

Comment: where is the problem? you are not allowed to append `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You should add judgement for `nil` like this:

```
-(NSMutableString*)pageStringToPrint {

    NSMutableString * cnoteString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [cnoteString setString:@"Class: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.note.classname ?: @""];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nTeacher: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.note.teacher ?: @""];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nSource: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.note.source ?: @""];
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nTopic: "];
    [cnoteString appendString:self.note.topic ?: @""];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.note.date] ?: @"";
    [cnoteString appendString:@"\nDate: "];
    [cnoteString appendString: dateString];  

    cnoteString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div id=\"mainContainer\"><div id=\"header\">%@</div>",[cnoteString kv_encodeHTMLCharacterEntities]];
```

Comment: @luk2302, if you mean this code ` [cnoteString appendString: dateString] ` ? The vary `dateString` is not `nil`.

Comment: Ah yes, not the `appendString` is the problem but the `[dateFormat stringFromDate:self.note.date ?: @""]`: you cannot pass `@""` to that function - sry for the confusion.

Comment: if i delete [cnoteString setString or appendString:@"Class: "]; its working fine.but i need to show Class name.

Comment: @luk2302, thank you for reminder. I'm carelessness to ignore the type of this variable

Comment: Vignes can you add more code regarding how do you create the self.note.classname variable? Since the problem is this string, we can help with it.

Comment: @Vignesh, you should make sure that the value of `self.note.classname` is not nil if you want to show

Comment: Which code is to create `self.note.classname` within your code above?

Comment: @Vignesh, I think that the important code is inside the method "saveCNote", can you post it too? The viewDidLoad doesn't do anything interesting,

Comment: @MarcoPace posted saveCnote